# Unable to format partitioned 32 GB micro SD card

Tags: partitioning, mbr, sd-card, format, filesystem-corruption

I am unable to format my 32 GB micro SDHC card after I made two partitions on it.
First partition is FAT32.
Second is 4 GB ext3.

Now I am unable to format my card and delete partitions on it.
It seems to get locked. Data and partitions remain intact, even after formatting.

P.S. I tried tools like EASUS, minitool, HP format utility, but nothing helps. And I am using the SD card adapter on my ASUS laptop.

Edit: It's a micro SD card. Pics attached!

[image: Partition Management window]

[image: Formatting dies with Error after 21%; error number 0x04]

Comment: [Try this utility](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/)

Comment: You need to erase and recreate the mbr. to get rid of the partitions.

Comment: What operating system are you using? What exact steps are you trying? What exact error messages, if any, are you receiving?

Comment: @Moab I already tried it. It prompts "Card is locked". Any other way ?

Comment: @Andie2302 Please elaborate the methods and step for deleting and recreating MBR.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I am using Windows 8.1 and i tried various apps for doing so on win platform, also i tried it UBUNTU too.

Comment: [Some sdhc cards have a physical switch on them](http://www.wikihow.com/Remove-Write-Protection-on-an-SD-Card) to put them in read only mode.

Answer (score 2):

If you can boot a Linux OS which has physical access to the SD device, you might try the following.

First, be sure to identify the device. Often, you might plug your key, then run `dmesg`. It usually tells you something. Let's pretend it is about `/dev/sdi` (but be careful, a mistake could wipe all your data!; don't use `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sdb` these are probably real hard disks).

So run first

```
fdisk -l /dev/sdi
```

to be convinced from the output that it is indeed your SD thing.

Then, wipe the entire partition (and lose all the SD data!) with

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdi bs=4k count=32768
```

then use `fdisk` or `gparted`  to remake the disk partitionning, and finally run `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdi3`  to e.g. make an EXT4 file system on the 3rd partition of your SD thing.

Be very careful (notably, replace `/dev/sdi`  by the relevant `/dev/sd`*x* thing where *x* is the appropriate letter).

Comment: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdi bs=4k count=32768` worked

Comment: Probably not. The `i` letter of `/dev/sdi` is likely to be wrong on *your* computer. You need to find out which letter it is.

Answer (score 1):

2 things can be going on here:

- The information in the first sector (the MBR) is corrupted which confuses the hell out of the Operating System. This prevents normal tools to properly wipe it.
  It should be possible to bring it back in usable shape but you won't be able to do that in Windows. Windows doesn't know how to handle multi-partition USB-removable devices (which is what the card-reader presents itself as to Windows) in thw first place and refuses to work in a normal way if it sees a partition table with more than 1 partition.
  I recommend you try the GPartED live-CD (or USB-stick). You should be able to write a fresh MBR or GPT partition table to the card. If that doesn't work see the next point below.
- The card is damaged and doesn't actually write anything properly anymore. In that case throw it away and get another.

Answer (score 0):

To erase the MBR in Windows you need a Low Level Format tool like [this](http://hddguru.com/software/HDD-LLF-Low-Level-Format-Tool/HDDLLF.4.40.exe) from [HDD-Guru](http://hddguru.com/software/HDD-LLF-Low-Level-Format-Tool/).
Now start the programm with administrator rights.

Click on:

- Continue for free
- Choose your sdhc card (be sure to choose the right one)
- Click Continue
- On the tab "LOW-LEVEL-FORMAT" choose "Perform quick wipe"
- Click on "FORMAT THIS DEVICE"

Now all Partitions on the sdhc should be removed. And you can format it in Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not working. Error: Unable to format. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

1: If your card is "locked" like you mention, you need to physically **unlock** it using the physical switch on the side of the card.

2: Doing a "Low-Level" format like suggested will do the trick but it's way more work than needed. You can easily re-partition the card or reset the MBR using a portable/small program like [BootIce](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/bootice.html)

Here's how to do it:
~ Select the SD Card from the "Destination Disk", drop down menu.
~ Click "Parts Manage"
[image: Step 1]
~ Select "Format this part" if it has 1 partition.
[image: Step2/3]
OR
~ Select "Re-Partitioning" if the drive has more than 1 partition and then decrease/delete all extra partition until only one is remaining. This option also allows for changing the partition tables (ie: starting at first sector, multiple entries, etc...)
~ You can also access or change the MBR/PBR information (BOOTMGR/GRUB4DOS/NTLDR boot) by clicking "Process MBR/PBR" instead of "Parts Manage" in the first step.

Comment: I am getting error 0x04 on reformatting.

Comment: And there is no physical lock, as it's a microsd

Comment: I don't know of any laptop computer that has a "MicroSD" card clot. Plus you mention you're using a Micro to SD Card adapter, **that** does have a lock.

Comment: I tried it with both USB sd card adapter (with nolock provided on it) and micro sd card adapter (lock opened). I am getting error 0x04. Please see pics attached. http://s30.postimg.org/ej15jszch/image.jpg http://s13.postimg.org/muj98fs5j/Error.jpg Thanks for your efforts !

Comment: That image isn't of an error. Have you tried doing each/all of the options? ie: repartitioning, format, **and** Process MBR/PBR?

Comment: Yes I tried all. On reformatting i am getting error "Write file failed.Access is denied"

Comment: Any other suggestions. Any other details you might need ?

Comment: One interesting thing I notice is on selecting sector edit 4 partitions are showing up last 2 ones with address 0x00 but originally i made only two partitions. Note : 1st as fat32 of around 21 gb primary partition and 2nd as ext3 of 4 gb hidden. Later one is for swap purposes used by 'LegacyXperia custom rom' [link] (forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2545354) and there is script which is advised by developer to run.